# Process finished with exit code 0, discord bot, what's wrong here?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a moderator bot but when i launch the code python writes "Process finished with exit code 0". Please check my if something wrong.

```
import discord
import config # Config is a another py file
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(config.ID)
    badwords = ["testword", "testword2"]
    unwarnusers = (config.unwarnusers)
    for word in badwords:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            if str(message.author) not in unwarnusers:
                warnFile = open("E:/vp2/warns.txt", "a")
                warnFile.write(str(message.author.mention) + "\n")
                warnFile.close()
                warnFile = open("E:/vp2/warns.txt", "r")
                warnedUsers = []
                for line in warnFile:
                    warnedUsers.append(line.strip())
                warnFile.close()
                warns = 0
                for user in warnedUsers:
                    if str(message.author.mention) == user:
                        warns += 1
                if warns > 4:
                    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name = "JB-MUTED")
                    await message.author.add_roles(mutedRole)
                channel = client.get_channel(959128819137146900)
                await channel.send(f"\nUser {message.author.mention} made something bad. \nHe writes:\n{message.content}\nThis happened in {message.channel}\n Warns: {warns}")
```

Comment: You forgot to call `client.run()`

Answer (score 0):

Add `client.run('token')` to the bottom of your code.